# Best way to map DTOs and entities in a Clean Architecture node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dto, clean-architecture

I am learning **Clean Architecture** using **Typescript/node.js** and struggling to find the best way to **map DTOs (Data Transfer Objects) and Domain Entities**.

DTOs are used to transfer data between the presentation layer (web server) and the application layer (use cases).

I found many resources online advising various design patterns to achieve this in various languages :

- Mappers (though it's not a design pattern)
- Factories
- Builders
- ...

In his book "Clean Architecture", Robert C. Martin talks about "adapters" but I could not find any explicit example of implementation.

**What would be the best and most accurate design decision for long-term development ?**

## Base code

**User DTO**

```
interface IUserDTO {

    id: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
    age: number;

}
```

**User entity**

```
interface IUser {

    getId(): string;

    setFirstName(firstName: string): void;
    getFirstName(): string;

    setLastName(lastName: string): void;
    getLastName(): string;

    setEmail(email: string): void;
    getEmail(): string;

    setAge(age: number): void;
    getAge(): number;
    
}

class User implements IUser {

    private _id: string;
    private _firstName:string;
    private _lastName: string;
    private _email: string;
    private _age: number;

    getId(): string {
        return this._id;
    }
    
    setFirstName(firstName: string): void {
        this._firstName = firstName;
    }

    getFirstName(): string {
        return this._firstName;
    }

    setLastName(lastName: string): void {
        this._lastName = lastName;
    }

    getLastName(): string {
        return this._lastName;
    }
        
    setEmail(email: string): void {
        this._email = email;
    }
    
    getEmail(): string {
        return this._email;
    }

    setAge(age: number): void {
        this._age = age;
    }

    getAge(): number {
        return this._age;
    }

}
```

## Proposal : Implementing a mapper against interfaces

But, though it's commonly adopted, is it an acceptable design pattern ?

```js
class UserMapper implements IToDtoMappable<IUser, IUserDto> {

    toDto(entity: IUser): IUserDto {
        const dto: IUserDto = {
            id: entity.getId(),
            firstName: entity.getFirstName(),
            lastName: entity.getLastName(),
            email: entity.getEmail(),
            age: entity.getAge(),
        };
        return dto;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you thought of implementing DTOs as classes that share some interface with a common function like "buildDTO" or whatever, and implement that function differently in each DTO to build data given the entity?

Comment: @victorperezpiqueras Yes, but I think it would go against the Clean Architecture decoupling principles.